# How are vector operations performed on 20newsgroups_vectorized data set?

Tags: vector, scikit-learn, text-database

When I fetch `20newsgroups_vectorized` data by

```
newsgroups = fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized(subset='all')
labels = newsgroups.target_names
target = newsgroups.target
target = pd.DataFrame([labels[i] for i in target], columns=['label'])
data = newsgroups.data
```

`data` is the `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` with the shape
`(18846, 130107)`

How can I subset the data by target names (for example, extract only `'rec.sport.baseball'`) and use vector operations on those sparse row vectors (for example, calculate the mean vector or the distances)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, subsetting the data by target names option is not available in `fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized` but it is available in 
`fetch_20newsgroups`, just that you have to vectorize the data yourself.

Here is how you can do it.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',
                                      categories=['rec.sport.baseball'])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
print(vectors.shape)
# (994, 13986)
```

Read more [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#usage)